# What account permissions are needed to authorise the API to access all of the courses and all coursework

Tags: google-classroom

I am trying to access all of the courses and coursework from the Google Classroom API.

However, when I authenticate as an admin user in GSuite only the courses I am enrolled in are returned by the API.  What level of user in GSuite would I need to be able to access all the courses?

The only way I achieved getting access to all of the courses and coursework from the Google Classroom API was to be a SuperAdmin user. I have reviewed the documentation supplied by Google however I haven't been able to find a solution other than being the SuperAdmin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I'm from G Suite Support, at this moment only SuperAdmins can access to curses where they are not enrolled. However you can open a Feature request on the following [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191645&template=823908)