# How to allow a service account to receive the entire list of courses that are in the Classroom domain?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, google-classroom

I'm a Google Admin super admin and when I try to get a list of all courses I get all the courses that are in my domain. Is there a way to allow another account to get a list of courses that are in the domain, but without granting super administrator rights, but only to view them?

Answer (score 0):

Your in the same issue in this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56758008/what-account-permissions-are-needed-to-authorise-the-api-to-access-all-of-the-co?rq=1), you can also use this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com) to open a feature request.

Comment: what should be specified, what is the second link for?

Comment: seems the features you are looking for are not available yet, you can create a feature request from this https://issuetracker.google.com , to process or to develop this feature to the GCP